# How to set same styles for different tags using styled-components and without CSS files

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a single-page website where I want every section to have the same primary style. The problem is that one section is `header`, the other `footer`, and the rest `div`. I would like to know the best way to use `styled-components` to achieve this behaviour. In CSS, I would have a selector `.section` in a global styles file, but as I understand, the `styled-components GlobalStyle` is only used to set general styling. If I want to use `styled-components` I will end up repeating the same code for every section. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JavaScript and CSS.
Then add the style (your CSS tag) to the _app.css file.
Then you can use the style on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to handle the CSS part from the styled-components. So you should use a global style CSS file. For all common CSS

For more reference follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xFDXO8tt7o)